# Consuming Multipart form data in Jersey REST API

Tags: java, jersey, multipartform-data, jersey-2.0

I am trying receive multipart form data in my REST services. I have used jersey 2.x for setting up my rest services.

I have downloaded the jersey-media-multipart-2.0-m11.jar from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-multipart/2.0-m11 (Note that I am not using maven to manage my dependencies - I am directly downloading jars)

Next, I updated my ResourceConfig class as follows:

```
public class ApplicationLauncher extends ResourceConfig{
    public ApplicationLauncher(){
            //register other resources
            register(MultiPartFeature.class);
        }
```

My server starts up properly, but when my REST API is called which consumes multipart form data, I get the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey] in context with path [/KwizzieServer] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/message/internal/HeaderUtils] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.HeaderUtils
```

Am I missing any dependent jars? or am I missing some configuration?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you are missing jersey common 2.0-m11**

> see http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-common/2.0-m11

I would strongly recommend you to use maven. If you don't then you can expect that you will see ClassNotFoundException many times and after some time management of dependencies becomes a nightmare.